# Equation Alignment!

Tags: equations, citing, align

[image: paper]

I am having a hard time doing this format. Does anyone know how to do this? It will be a big help if anyone does. Thank you so much.

This is what I did:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \lambda_{N} &= \ln N  \text{{\itshape NBIC/SC} \citep{t}}\\
    \lambda_{N} &= 2 \text{{\itshape AIC} \citep{a}}\\
    \lambda_{N} &= 1 +\ln N  \text{{\itshape CAIC} \citep{e}}\\
    \lambda_{N} &= 2 \ln\ln N \text{{\itshape HQIC} \citep{o}}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

This is what shows..
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Use aligned instead of split. Split only support one alignment column. And then add && in front of the four`\text` commands

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Please help. I edited the question already

Comment: Next time please provide what Christian ask for. You provided a snippet. But we cannot see which packages you've loaded or which class you are using. Providing these and thus making the mwe compilable without having to add anything to it, makes it at lot easier for others to help.

Comment: Put a compilable code, for example `amsmath` or `mathtools` is missing. There is not a package for what `\citep{...}` works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,natbib}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation} 
  \begin{aligned} 
  \lambda_{N} &= \ln N      && \text{{\itshape NBIC/SC} \citep{t}}\\
   \lambda_{N} &= 2         && \text{{\itshape AIC} \citep{a}}\\
    \lambda_{N} &= 1 +\ln N && \text{{\itshape CAIC} \citep{e}}\\
     \lambda_{N} &= 2 \ln N && \text{{\itshape HQIC} \citep{o}} 
   \end{aligned} 
   \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]